# How to view the output of c++ program which compiled on terminal

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++, output

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);

    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a+b;    
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it from terminal(Mac), it is not read meaning from input.txt and do not write to output.txt. What is the problem?

Comment: Check the return values of `freopen` and `errno`.

Comment: @not-rightfold How to check it. I work on terminal at the first time. Before I used another programs.

Comment: Eh, well, using `if` and `errno`. vOv

Comment: Did you get any compile error due to missing #include <cstdio>? Add the following code:

Comment: freopen is declared in stdio.h

Comment: @VishnuKanwar, OP is using C++ code, so the norm should to use C++ headers.

Comment: @Chingy, Add the following code to check the problem:     if(!freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin)) cout << "Error attaching stdin \n";  if(!freopen("output.txt", "w", stdin)) cout << "Error attaching stdout \n";

Comment: @user2784234 NO output.

Comment: @Chingy, Output will be in "output.txt" not on Terminal.

Comment: @user2784234 Yes I know. But there is nothing I can send some screenshots if you wish.

Comment: @Chingy, please do...

Comment: @user2784234 https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1mzaighvyflris/1.jpg

Comment: the same code works file on linux. (tested on Linux 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) 
Issue might related to MAC check the return values of freopen

Comment: @VishnuKanwar https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1mzaighvyflris/1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chingy, I saw your screenshot. Please look at this [documentation](http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html) for basic introduction to g++. Please note that the compilation and execution of a program are different instances.

First step is compilation, which you are doing correctly as per the screenshot.
1) g++ 1.cpp.

This step will create an executable (a.out) which you need to run separately in order to get the desired behavior from your program.

Please execute the program as follows:
2) ./a.out

Comment: What command should be written to immediately show the answer IN terminal.However program should read input data from input.txt

Comment: Remove `freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);` and re-compile and re-execute.

Comment: Saw your second dropbox. Remove all the changes suggested in this post. Run your original program, using the "compile" and "execute" steps, and check "output.txt".

Comment: YES. IT WORKS!!! Do you know any optimized way to execute the result. I mean only one command to do all this things suck as compile then ./a.out execution

Comment: @Chingy, there is none. That's the difference between Compiled Language (such as C++) and Interpreted Language (such as Python). Please google to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close files gracefully

```
fclose (stdin);
fclose (stdout);
```

Note: The fclose() function flushes the stream pointed to by stdout (writing any buffered output data using fflush and closes the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: Exiting the program should automatically close the files, so the OP does not need to.

Comment: In the beautiful world of embedded platform, it's really hard to say what would happens. However, if I was in your situation, I'd just manually test to see if the file ID are really released.. And, if space is that important, maybe you could document this fact elsewhere.

Comment: the same code works file on linux.
(tested on Linux 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)